# Is it possible to insert a visual force page in the custom object layout?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, page-layout, related-list, standard-objects

```
    Public Class SalesOrderLayoutCom{
        public List<Sales_Order__c> OrderIdList{get;set;}
        public List<Sales_Order__c> oppIdList{get;set;}
        Public SalesOrderLayoutCom() {
            OrderIdList=new List<Sales_Order__c>();
            oppIdList=new List<Sales_Order__c>();
            OrderIdList=[Select id from Sales_Order__c where Opportunity__r.StageName='Closed Won'];
            //oppIdList=[Select Id from Opportunity where Sales_Order__c.id  in : OrderIdList];

        }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask in this post. First, yes, it is okay to insert a VF page into custom page layout. Second, what is your point for pasting this piece of code? It doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add visual force page in the custom object layout. Here is how.

To be able to embed a Visual Force page into page layout, the VF page should be using the standard Controller tag referencing same entity for which this page will be used in page layout . You can use/add this visual force page by modifying the page layout.

A simple Visual force page using the Standard Opportunity Controller.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information">
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.closeDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

After this, this page should show in Page Layout editor and can be embedded on a page layout for Opportunity.

**Here is a reference screenshot showing how to add VF page in layout.**
[image]

Source: - 1 - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US 
Source: - 2 - http://support.drawloop.com/loop-storage/create-custom-visualforce-page

Comment: @Ravi f it was the answer can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.